# Mock a bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have to mock a bluetooth device that would first pair with an Android device and then send predefined data to an Android app. 
I have no access to source code of the app, but I managed to get bluetooth communication packets sent between devices (using wireshark and btsnoop_hci.log).
After pairing is done, data could be sent in an infinite loop.

Having this limited info, is there a way to mock such a bluetooh device?
Can it be done on a PC or additional hardware is needed?

I'm not a developer, but I have some minor programming experience, mostly in JAVA. Any hint on the subject would be beneficial.

Comment: can i contact you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn your Smartphone in peripheral mode

Here are some infos on how to do this:
https://www.quora.com/What-all-Android-phones-support-BLE-peripheral-mode